# Codeigniter- loading model w/ contruct & passed var

Tags: codeigniter, model, constructor

So here is what I have...

class User_Data extends CI_Model{

```
var $id,
    $first_name,
    $last_name,
    $name;

public function __construct($init_data) {
    parent::__construct();

    if(isset($init_data))
    {
     ...
    }
```

My issue is that when I load the model into the controller, it shoots an error:

> Message: Missing argument 1 for User_Data::__construct()

But even with the error on load, it does what I want when I create a new instance.

If anyone could lead me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the argument or set a default value:

```
public function __construct($init_data = 0)
```